# calculate distance between different entries in one column

Tags: sql, postgresql, distance, point

I have this kind of column in my table:

```
Table A:

geom_etrs(geometry)
"0101000020E8640000FE2EAF0B3C981C414E499E34DFE65441"
"0101000020E864..."
"0101000020E875..."
"0101000020E867..."
```

How can I calculate the distances between each of the entries (they are already defined as `POINT`)?

I want to create a new column where the distances between 1 and 2, then between 2 and 3, then between 3 and 4 and so on, are displayed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    select st_distance(point, lead(point,1) over (partition by rn)) 
 from ( select point, row_number() over (partition by id) as rn
 from table_1)t;


    gis=# \d users
     user_id | bigint    |  
     geog    | geography | 

select st_astext(geog), st_astext(lead(geog,1) over (partition by rn)) from ( select geog, row_number() over (partition by user_id) as rn from users limit 10)t;
                 st_astext                 |                 st_astext                 
-------------------------------------------+-------------------------------------------
 POINT(-70.0777937636872 41.6670617084209) | POINT(-70.0783833464664 41.6675384387944)
 POINT(-70.0783833464664 41.6675384387944) | POINT(-70.0793901822679 41.667476122803)
 POINT(-70.0793901822679 41.667476122803)  | POINT(-70.0787530494335 41.6671461707966)
 POINT(-70.0787530494335 41.6671461707966) | POINT(-70.07908017161 41.6663672501228)
 POINT(-70.07908017161 41.6663672501228)   | POINT(-70.0795407352778 41.6669886861798)
 POINT(-70.0795407352778 41.6669886861798) | POINT(-70.0798881265976 41.6663775240468)
 POINT(-70.0798881265976 41.6663775240468) | POINT(-70.0781470955597 41.6667824284963)
 POINT(-70.0781470955597 41.6667824284963) | POINT(-70.0790447962989 41.6675773546665)
 POINT(-70.0790447962989 41.6675773546665) | POINT(-70.0778760883834 41.6675017901701)
 POINT(-70.0778760883834 41.6675017901701) |

 gis=# select st_distance(geog, lead(geog,1) over (partition by rn)) from ( select geog, row_number() over (partition by user_id) as rn from users limit 10)t;
 st_distance  
--------------
  72.21147623
  84.13511302
  64.48606246
  90.70040367
  78.96272466
  73.78817244
 151.81026032
 115.69092832
  97.69189128
```

This should work for you

Answer (score 0):

Using [window function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/tutorial-window.html) `LEAD` gives you the next value as new column next to the current value: [demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=3ee40e97d5b4d7035bb83ed2785af830) (only with `text` type because the fiddle does not support `geometry`, but it's the same)

```
SELECT 
    point_column,
    LEAD(point_column) OVER ()
FROM
    table
```

Now you are able to calculate the distance with PostGIS' [`st_distance`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Distance.html):

```
SELECT 
    st_distance(
        point_column,
        LEAD(point_column) OVER ()
    )
FROM
    table
```